# Iterate through a hash. However, my value is changing every time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm currently working on a simple hash loop, to manipulate some json data. Here's my Json data:

```
{
 "polls": [
   { "id": 1, "question": "Pensez-vous utiliser le service de cordonnerie/pressing au moins 2 fois par mois ?" },
   { "id": 2, "question": "Avez-vous passé une bonne semaine ?" },
   { "id": 3, "question": "Le saviez-vous ? Il existe une journée d'accompagnement familial." }
 ],
 "answers": [
   { "id": 1, "poll_id": 1, "value": true },
   { "id": 2, "poll_id": 3, "value": false },
   { "id": 3, "poll_id": 2, "value": 3 }
 ]
}
```

I want to have the poll_id value and the value from the answers hash. So here's what I code :

```
require 'json'

file = File.read('data.json')
datas = JSON.parse(file)

result = Hash.new

datas["answers"].each do |answer|
  result["polls"] = {"id" => answer["poll_id"], "value" => answer["value"]}
end
polls_json = result.to_json
```

However, it returns me :

```
{
  "polls": {
    "id": 2,
    "value": 3
  }
}
```

Here's the output i am looking for :

```
{
  "polls": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "value": true
    },
   {
      "id": 2,
      "value": 3
    },
   {
      "id": 3,
      "value": false
   }
 ]
}
```

It seems that the value is not saved into my loop. I've tried different method but I still cannot find a solution .. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you give an example of what the desired output is? (as code, by editing the question please.)

Comment: Yes of course !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `reduce` here, i.e.

```
datas["answers"].reduce({ polls: [] }) do |hash, data|
  hash[:polls] << { id: data["poll_id"], value: data["value"] }
  hash
end
```

This method iterates through the answers, making available the object supplied to `reduce` (in this case a hash with a `:polls` array) to which we pass each data hash.

I'd personally, um, reduce this a little further with the following, although it's at some cost to readability:

```
datas["answers"].reduce({ polls: [] }) do |hash, data|
  hash.tap { |h| h[:polls] << { id: data["poll_id"], value: data["value"] } }
end
```

It's the cleanest method to achieve what you're looking for, using a built-for-purpose method.

Docs for `reduce` here: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce

(I'd also be inclined to update the variable names - data is already plural, so 'datas' is a little confusing to anyone else coming to your code.)

---

Edit: @max makes a great point re symbol / string keys from your data - keep that in mind if you attempt to apply this.

Comment: Wow thanks for all your explanations, it's way more clear than it was!

Comment: I'm currently trying with your code. However, I think i'm doing something in a  wrong way because it returns me an empty hash. Could you help me with that ?

Comment: I think this will come down to what was mentioned earlier about stringified / symbolised keys. `:polls` will always be a symbol, though if you do `JSON.parse(your_data)` the keys will be strings (as in the answer), if _not_ then they'll be symbols (i.e. `{ id: data[:poll_id], value: data[:value] }`). See if that helps!

Comment: It was my mistake, my bad. Thanks for your answer anyway !

Comment: I have an other issue ... Do you mind if I update my question to show you what my trouble is ? I cannot find any solution on internet/stack and I think the reduce method is the good to do it.

Answer (score 0):

try the below:

```
require 'json'

file = File.read('data.json')
datas = JSON.parse(file)

result = Hash.new
poll_json = []

datas["answers"].each do |answer|
  poll_json << {"id" => answer["poll_id"], "value" => answer["value"]}
end
p "json = "#{poll_json}"
```

Comment: It worked ! Many thanks. However, i think result is not needed here right  ?

Comment: Hum there's still something.... I want poll_json to have the name "polls". Like in my code, `result["polls"]`. (If I didnt made myself clear, try to run my code in your console) Any idea ?

Comment: This is because you are saving the array in the hash object, each time the value of object gets overriden

Comment: You can rename polls instead of poll_json

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  polls: datas["answers"].map do |a|
    { id: a["poll_id"], value: a["value"] }
  end
}
```

In general use `.map` to iterate through arrays and hashes and return new objects. `.each` should only be used when you are only concerned about the side effects (like in a view when you are outputting values).

```
require 'json'

json = JSON.parse(File.read('data.json'))

result = {
  polls: json["answers"].map do |a|
    { id: a["poll_id"], value: a["value"] }
  end
}

puts result.to_json
```

The output is:

```
{"polls":[{"id":1,"value":true},{"id":3,"value":false},{"id":2,"value":3}]}
```

Comment: I do not understand ... Where I run your code, I have an empty hash.

Comment: If you are copying the hash from your question to ruby the keys will be symbols while they will be strings if you are decoding JSON.

Comment: Since hashes are not indifferent they will give different results. If you change it to `datas[:answers].map { { id: a[:poll_id], value: a[:value] } }` it will give the same result with symbol keys.

Comment: Hum, one more things. Let's imagine that my Json have many answers for one poll_id. Should I still use the map method ? For exemple the id = 2 have two answers, do I have to loop `value: a[:value] }`?

Comment: Then you would use reduce. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce